# Detecting unnecessary Files and Folders in Laravel and Delete them

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, server, laravel-8

I am trying to create an online Resume Maker using PHP laravel authentication with Breeze. I am using a shared hosting with limited number of inode usage quota of 10k. Now the problem with Laravel is that upon uploading to the shared hosting it is consuming 90% of the inode usage quota with its bulk files. So my question is if there is a way to have a more selective empty Laravel project or if someone knows the names of unnecessary Laravel files or folders that can be deleted (which will not break the application from functioning properly), as servers often have limited Inodes and 8,000 files + folders for every project makes you reach the limit really quickly. As at now am getting errors that 'cannot open stream as inode quota is reached'.

Comment: You can use a package that will allow you to write policies: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-directory-cleanup

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all files included in this folder (please backup your project before):

1. Database/Factory --> all your factory files except UserFactory.php
2. Database/Migrations--> all your migration files
3. Database/Seeder --> all your seeder files except DatabaseSeeder.php
4. Unused your assets files
5. Vendor/Faker --> only remove files

You can also remove some other vendor/.../phpfiles, if yout dosn't use its feature in your project.